# Is method chaining slow C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

So for example, which of these is faster:

```
if(object.GetMemberX().IsSomething())
{
    Store(object.GetMemberX());
    object.GetMemberX().FlagSomething();
}
```

or

```
typeX x = object.GetMemberX();
if(typeX.IsSomething())
{
    Store(x);
    x.FlagSomething();
}
```

I imagine that if `GetMemberX()` returns a pointer or a reference then in the first example, the compiler can't optimize away the two calls because it has no guarantee that the returned pointer/reference is the same for each invocation?

But in the second example I'm storing it?

If this is true, does it only apply to methods that return a pointer/reference? If my methods return by value will they benefit / be hindered by the different calls?

Comment: guessing at what the optimizer can and can't do is generally pretty tough to do... things like dereferencing a function shouldn't take much time anyway... if you are in some sort of a tight loop where performance is critical you should profile and see what is taking the time

Comment: Benchmark it in a context that matters to you.

Comment: Is `IsSomething` a static function here?

Comment: Thanks, im really interested in knowing a general rule though.

Comment: Using the temporary `typeX x` changes the code at `FlagSomething` if `GetMemberX` returns a references.

Comment: @BDL no, regular method

Comment: @David There can't be a general rule because it completely depends on what the different functions do. As long as the compiler can prove that the code will do the same independent of whether `GetMemberX` is called once or three times it can do it. But whether it can prove such a thing is complicated to decide even in specific cases.

Comment: @Voo Even if the compiler can optimize the duplicate call away, it should be avoided for readability.

Comment: The two snippets are *not* equivalent.  Having the compiler optimizer prove that another thread won't change the underlying member that produces the GetMemberX() return value isn't exactly straight-forward.

Comment: There simply isn't enough information to answer this. It really depends on many things, most of which you have omitted from the code you posted. In any case, the way to know is to profile both versions in a realistic running scenario.

Comment: @DavidMurphy: If it's not a static method, `typeX.IsSomething()` will not work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version is more readable. However, it may invoke the copy constructor of `typeX`. To be readable *and* fast, use a reference or pointer:

```
typeX& x = object.GetMemberX();
if(typeX.IsSomething())
{
    Store(x);
    x.FlagSomething();
}
```

The only case where you shouldn't use a reference is when `object.GetMemberX()` returns by value, in that case your second version is the way to go. In that case, storing the return value does not incur overhead because the compiler can optimize the copy away (copy elision).

Comment: Can you expand on this, please? Why is it faster? Does it apply to values and references the same?

Comment: First version was a bit off, I corrected it now. The reference is faster simply because you avoid an unnecessary function call, which takes at least ten to twenty CPU cycles.

Comment: So, if returning by value, I shouldnt chain. If returning by reference or pointer I shouldnt chain? Dont ever chain?

Comment: Or just ignore the whole problem and write `decltype(auto) x = obj.GetMemberX();`

Answer (score 5):

This question cannot be answered in the C++ general context ... because it depends on the compiler implementation and optimisation level !

You even cannot be sure that a particular compiler at a particular optimisation level would not generate exactly same code for both versions, because ultimately the actions should be the same.

My advice is to just use the common rule : first write code that is readable (by you and if possible peers ...). When comes the question for performance, profile the program and only optimize the small parts that deserve it, always by benchmarking the different possibilities.

Of course the above concerns mainly low level optimisation like what you are asking here. You should always choose algorythms coherent with the expected usage ...